# Why does my Windows 10 PC show my default gateway's address instead of the DNS Server IP adresses I've set?

Tags: windows-10, ipconfig

When I go to `cmd` and type `ipconfig /all` I can see that the DNS Servers' IP addresses are simply the address of my default gateway (router). Why? When I go to my router settings it does not matter if I set to get dynamically from ISP or set 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 for example, my PC still tells me that my DNS Servers' IP addresses are the IP address of my router.
Can anybody explain to me why is this happening and how to fix that?
Thank you.

Here's some settings of my router:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The information you pc uses is most likely set from DHCP.
Probably it is your router that is the DHCP server as well. Many configurations sends the DNS servers as is, while other routers run a proxy DNS service, and in that case the DNS address could be set to the same as the router. Many such routers are known to be insecure, but not all of them are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your router uses the DNS servers you configure it to use. It in turn assigns itself as the DNS server for it's DHCP clients. That's a pretty standard configuration. The DHCP clients send DNS queries to the router, which in turn sends those queries to it's configured DNS servers.

There may be options to configure what DNS servers are assigned to DHCP clients in the DHCP Server configuration of the router. Take a look at the DHCP server options of the router and see.

Comment: I've added some screenshot. I did set the addresses of Google DNS servers: _Network -> Internet -> Advanced Settings._ Perhaps if I set the same addresses for the DHCP Server I'll be able to see them while typing `ipconfig /all`. I just don't get it why do I have to set the same DNS Servers' addresses twice.

Comment: Yes, you need to set those same DNS servers in the DHCP server settings. Why do you have to do it twice? Because they are two different functions; `1.` What does the router use for it's DNS? `2.` What do the DHCP clients use for their DNS? - It's not a given that you want to use the same DNS servers for both functions.

Comment: I'm the only one person who uses this machine. What will happen if I for example set the OpenDNS servers' addresses for my network configuration and Google DNS servers' addresses for my DHCP Server? If I type _www.google.com_ then where would my browser go in order to resolve the IP address?

Answer (score 1):

> When I go to cmd and type ipconfig /all I can see that the DNS Servers' IP addresses are simply the address of my default gateway (router). Why?

Because that's the way it's been set up by the DHCP server - likely the same device even.

> When I go to my router settings it does not matter if I set to get dynamically from ISP or set 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.

On your router you configure *your router's* DNS server. To change *your client's* DNS server, change the DHCP server's scope options.

On many consumer-grade all-in-one routers you can't change the DHCP options but I don't think these things are on-topic here.